# not able to send email

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

My website is hosted on a Godaddy server. I am trying to send an email but i am getting "The operation has timed out." error. I have tried following links but its not working. 
[GoDaddy email sending failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691520/asp-net-hosting-on-godaddy-can-i-send-emails-from-username-and-not-from-email-a)

and 
[Not Able To Send Email Via C#](https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Email/Not-able-to-send-email-via-C/m-p/36339#M3341)

I have tried so far below code.

In web.config

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network host="smtpout.secureserver.net" userName="username" password="secret" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

and in code behind

```
var SmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
SmtpClient.Send(frommail,tomail,subject,body);
```

I have also tried below code

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtForgotEmail.Text));
msg.From = new MailAddress("email");
msg.Subject = "subject";
msg.Body = "msg body"
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("toemail", "secret");
client.Port = 25;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Send(msg);
```

P.S. i cant even send an email from localhost and also tried

```
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

[image]

Comment: did you tried with explicit ssl port i.e 587

Answer (score 0):

Try adding port to settings

```
 <network host="smtpout.secureserver.net" userName="username" password="secret" port=25/>
```

For what ports to use refer,

https://sg.godaddy.com/help/what-do-i-do-if-i-have-trouble-connecting-to-my-email-account-319

try all 25, 80, 3535 and 465 with SSL